# Why $P(x) = 0$ is equivalent to $\dfrac{P(x)}{P'(x)} = 0$ for every polynomial $P$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let's say we have the polynomial, $x^{4}+x^{3}+x^{2}+x$. It's derivative is, $4x^{3}+3x^{2}+2x+1$. The solutions to the original polynomial are, $-1$, $0$, $-i$, and $i$. When we divide $x^{4}+x^{3}+x^{2}+x$ by $4x^{3}+3x^{2}+2x+1$, it's solutions are, $-1$, $0$, $-i$, and $i$. The solutions are the same. This also happens for more complicated polynomials, and I am thinking it happens for all polynomials. If this does happen for all polynomials, what is the proof? If not, why does it happen so often?

Comment: For any two polynomials $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$, $P(x)=0\iff\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=0$.

Comment: If the derivative doesn't share any of the same roots as the original polynomial, then dividing by the derivative can't "kill" any of those roots.  Furthermore, dividing by a polynomial doesn't *introduce* any extra roots, because the polynomial never "blows up".  (Using very loose language here.) So, what can you say about the roots of a polynomial and its derivative? Do they every coincide?  Can you show a polynomial that shares a root with its derivative? Or, can you prove that such a thing never happens?  Try to see what happens first for quadratics.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos $P(x)/P(x) \neq 0$.

Comment: There's a little more to be said here.  Any multiple roots of a polynomial are roots of its derivative with multiplicity one less than the original polynomial.  So factoring out the greatest common divisor of a polynomial with its divisor removes any multiple roots.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos To be more precise, for any two polynomials $P(x)$ and $Q(x), P(x_0) = 0$ *and* $Q(x_0) \neq 0$ imply that $\frac{P}{Q}(x_0) = 0.$

Comment: A polynomial will have the same solutions of itself divided by *anything* (with observations might for zero denominators).  If $P(x) = 0$ for a set of solutions.  Then $\frac {P(x)}M = 0$ for *ANYTHING* that $M$ might be (assuming that $M \ne 0$ for that set of solutions.)

Comment: @AaronSpeedy A fraction is equal to $0$ iff its numerator is equal to $0$.

Comment: Nothing to do with polynomials. If $A =0$ and $M\ne 0$ then $A=0\implies \frac AM =A\times \frac 1M = 0\times \frac 1M=0$.  And if $\frac AM=0$ then $\frac AM\times M = 0\times M=0$ and $A = 0$. So for any $M \ne 0$ we have $A=0\iff \frac AM = 0$.  So if $P(x)=0$ for some solution set of $x$ and $Q(x)\ne 0$ for those set then $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} = P(x)\times \frac 1{Q(x)} = 0\times \frac 1{Q(x)}=0$.  Likewise if $\frac {P(x)}{Q(x)}=0$ for some set then $P(x)=\frac {P(x)}{Q(x)}\times Q(x)=0\times Q(x)=0$ for the same set.

Comment: So it stands to reason that if $P(x) = 0$ for $x=x_0,x_1,....$ and $P'(x)\ne 0$ for $x=x_0,x_1....$ then for $x=x_0,x_1,...$ that $\frac {P(x)}{P'(x)} = P(x)\times \frac 1{P'(x)} = 0\times \frac 1{P'(x)} = 0$.  And likewise if $\frac {P(x)}{P'(x)}=0$ for $x = x_a,x_b,x_c....$ then $P(x) =\frac {P(x)}{P'(x)}\times P'(x)=0\times P'(x)= 0$.  It has *nothing* to do with $P'(x)$ and has *everything* to do with $P(x) = 0$ for some values.

Comment: "Why would it preserve the zero solution?"  Because if a *NUMERATOR* is equal to zero then the entire fraction is equal to zero.  And if an entire fraction is equal to zero then the *NUMERATOR* must be equal to zero.   Whether a fraction is or is not equal to zero is determined (and thus "perserved") entirely by if the numerator is and has nothing to do with the denominator (except the denominator can never be zero).

Comment: @fleablood Oh. I need coffee

Comment: This thread above is confusing to follow. The comments are not where answers are supposed to be!

Comment: Andrei Murashev's 'answer' is **completely wrong**. Why did you accept it? Mike's answer is correct except for the last step, which was pointed out in the comments (and he agreed).

Comment: Answer editted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On can see the following:

> Claim 1: Iff a polynomial $P(x)$ has a root $r$ with multiplicity $k>0$ i.e., $(x-r)^k$ divides $P$ but $(x-r)^{k+1}$ does not, then $r$ is a root of $P'(x)$ with multiplicity exactly $k-1$.

[Indeed, let us write $P(x) = (x-r)^kQ(x)$, where $Q(x)$ is a polynomial that is nonzero at $x=r$. Then note that
$$P'(x) = k(x-r)^{k-1}Q(x) + (x-r)^kQ'(x),$$ where $Q'(x)$ is the derivative of $Q(x)$ with respect to $x$. As $(x-r)^k$ divides $(x-r)^kQ'(x)$ but not $k(x-r)^{k-1}Q(x)$, it follows that $(x-r)^k$ does not divide $P'(x)$. Can you see that on the other hand, $(x-r)^{k-1}$ does divide $P'(x)$?]

So if $P(x) = \prod_{i=1}^m (x-r_i)^{k_i}$, where $r_1,\ldots, r_m$ are the *distinct* roots of $P(x)$ and each $k_i$ is a *positive* integer, then for some polynomial $p(x)$ that is nonzero at each of $r_1,\ldots, r_m$, the derivative $P'(x)$ of $P(x)$ with respect to $x$ can be written
$$P'(x) = p(x)\prod_{i=1}^m (x-r_i)^{k_i-1}.$$

Can you take it from here. In particular, let $R(x)$ be the rational function
$$R(x) \doteq \frac{1}{p(x)} × \prod_{i=1}^m (x-r_i)^{k_i-k'_i},$$ where for each $i=1,\ldots, m$, the integer $k'_i$ is defined to be the largest integer such that $(x-r_i)^{k'_i}$ divides $P'(x)$. Then your question asks to prove the following: No matter the choice of non-constant polynomial $P(x)$, this rational function $R(x)$ is indeed defined and takes the value $0$ for $x=r_i$ for each $i=1,\ldots, m$. However, to this end, first use the fact established above that $k_i-k'_i$ is precisely $1$ for each such $i$. Next, note that $p(x)$ is nonzero at each of $r_1,\ldots, r_m$....

You can take it from there.

Comment: There are good reasons to consider $\frac{x^2}{2x}$ to be undefined at $x=0$ (to give a simple example). What you do in the last step is to "fill in the holes" in the domain of $P(x)/P'(x)$ at each multiple root of $P(x)$ in such a way as to produce a continuous function in neighborhoods of each of those points. The remarkable thing is that when we fill in these "holes" we do indeed get the same set of distinct roots. Nicely done. And of course if all roots are single roots we do not even have to "fill holes."

Comment: @David K you are correct. In my answer I did cut a corner and took $\frac{P(x)}{P'(x)} \doteq$ $\prod_{i=1}^n (x-r_i)^{k_i-k'_i}$, where: The $r_1,r_2, \ldots r_n$ are distinct complex numbers such that each $r_i$ is a root of at least one of $P$, $P'$. The integer $k_i$ is the largest integer such that $(x-r_i)^{k_i}$ divides $P(x)$, and the integer $k'_i$ is the largest integer such that $(x-k'_i)$ divides $P'(x)$.

Comment: So for example, if $P(x)=x^2$  I did take $\frac{P(x)}{P'(x)}$ to be $x/2$, even though it is really $\frac{x^2}{2x}$, the former is defined everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$, the latter is the same function as the former, *except* the latter has a point discontinuity at $x=0$.

Comment: @Mike. By $≐$, d‘you mean: [“approaches the limit”](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2250), [“conditional equality”](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+225B), or something else related to [$=$](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+003D)?

Comment: I used $\doteq$ to mean 'defined to be'. What I meant to say overall is that I took $\frac{P(x)}{P'(x)}$ to be the resulting function after common factors were cancelled out.

Comment: Anyway, in the field of rational fractions, it's correct.

Comment: Anyways just editted in light of the comments above.

Comment: @Mike. Thankye for the clarification. Fwiw, there are already three equals-symbols designated for “defined to be”: [$≔$](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2254), [$≝$](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+225D), and [$≕$](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2255); On the LHS of the former typically would be the more arbitrary object and on the RHS more of particular object (*à la* designated parameter), where …

Comment: …[cont'd] the latter is its dual, and the middle one has a flavor similar to [“identical-to”($≣$)](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2263) but typically closer semantically to the former than the latter (hinting at ascribement to standard convention modeling immutable law rather than an *ad hoc* adaptation for portrayal in the partic scenario).

Comment: It might be worth observing that there is an ‘equals’-style symbol [$⩦$](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2A66) that is a vertical mirror of “approaches the limit”-equality $≐$ which suggests that the dot-underneath version could be taken as the dual of its dot-above counterpart (although most explicit duality-counterpart relation symbols mirror horizontally, e.g. $>\text{ vs. }<$), i.e. perhaps meaning “is the limit” (rather than “the limit is”). A person versed in subject matter likely can understand what you mean with your choice of ad-hoc symbology given context, but worth recognizing.

Comment: I need to lookup how to put in latex the symbols you posted. I very well may have been using  "$\doteq$" incorrectly all this time.

Comment: @Mike: The usual notation for defining equality is either "$:=$" or "$\overset{Δ}=$".

Comment: Thanks! How do you type out in latex the latter symbol?

Comment: @Mike. pro-tip: You can see the LaTeX used by right-clicking and selecting "Show Math As". So for the case of [delta-equals($≜$)](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+225C) within dollar-signs it appears that user21820 HATES SMOKING-HATS used \overset{Δ}{=}. \Delta also presents as $\Delta$

Answer (score 1):

The division
$$
P(x)=P'(x)Q(x)+R(x)
$$
may yield a nonzero remainder, but it's not a real problem. As an easy example, the derivative of $x^2+1$ is $2x$ and we cannot do exact division.

The correct statement needs to use the greatest common divisor (which over polynomials is only defined up to a nonzero multiplicative constant).

**Theorem.** *If $D(x)$ is the (monic) greatest common divisor of $P(x)$ and $P'(x)$ and $P(x)=D(x)Q(x)$, then $Q(x)$ has the same roots as $P(x)$ and all roots of $Q(x)$ are simple.*

I assume that the base field is $\mathbb{C}$, but the argument works with any base field of characteristic $0$. With $x$ I denote an indeterminate; other lowercase letters denote elements of the base field; uppercase letters denote polynomials.

First a definition: $r$ is said to be a root of multiplicity $k$ of the polynomial $P(x), where $k$ is a nonnegative integer, if

1. $(x-r)^k$ divides $P(x)$, and
2. $(x-r)^{k+1}$ does not divide $P(x)$.

Of course, saying that $r$ is a root of multiplicity $0$ means it's not a root at all, but it's convenient for the sequel. A *simple root* is a root of multiplicity $1$.

The derivative satisfies the standard properties, in particular the product rule, and we have, if $P(x)=(x-r)^kQ(x)$,
$$
P'(x)=k(x-r)^{k-1}Q(x)+(x-r)^kQ(x)
$$
It follows that, if $r$ is a root of multiplicity $k$ of $P(x)$, then $r$ is a root of multiplicity $k-1$ of $P'(x)$ (exercise).

If $r_1,r_2,\dots,r_m$ is the complete set of distinct roots of $P(x)$, with respective multiplicities $k_1,k_2,\dots,k_m$, then
$$
P(x)=(x-r_1)^{k_1}(x-r_2)^{k_2}\dotsm(x-r_m)^{k_m}A(x)
$$
where $A(x)$ has no roots. Applying the argument above, we see that
$$
P'(x)=(x-r_1)^{k_1-1}(x-r_2)^{k_2-1}\dotsm(x-r_m-1)^{k_m-1}B(x)
$$
where none of $r_1,r_2,\dots,r_m$ is a root of $B(x)$. Now it's clear that we have, for the greatest common divisor,
$$
D(x)=(x-r_1)^{k_1-1}(x-r_2)^{k_2-1}\dotsm(x-r_m)^{k_m-1}C(x)
$$
and $C(x)$ is the greatest common divisor of $A(x)$ and $B(x)$, so it cannot have roots. Therefore we have proved that
$$
Q(x)=(x-r_1)(x-r_2)\dotsm(x-r_m)Q_0(x)
$$
where $Q_0(x)$ has no roots.

Now if we consider polynomials over $\mathbb{C}$ as functions, we have
$$
f(x)=\frac{P(x)}{P'(x)}=(x-r_1)(x-r_2)\dotsm(x-r_m)\frac{A(x)}{B(x)}
$$
which is defined where $B(x)\ne0$ and $A(x)$ has no roots, so the zeros of the function $f$ are the same as the zeros of $P(x)$.

Comment: You misread the question.....

Comment: @user21820HATESSMOKING-HATS Why do you think so?

Comment: You wrote "we cannot do exact division" but the question never said you could; it asks whether dividing a polynomial by its derivative does not change the zeros; it never said the result was a polynomial. So the question is not about whether the derivative is a divisor or not... Mike's answer addresses the question if his wrong last step is fixed.

Comment: @user21820HATESSMOKING-HATS I don't think it's a good way to go, but I added the final part that addresses your comments.

Comment: It's not whether it's a good way to go; it's simply what the asker is looking for. And the asker even gave an explicit example with complex roots, so you should ideally be talking about ℂ rather than ℝ or at least remarking on that special case. Thanks for adding the final part to your answer!

Comment: @user21820HATESSMOKING-HATS Changed $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$.